# autoincrementing primary key n entering data from frontend that is a web page

Tags: c#, database, winforms, primary-key

I created a table and autoincremented the primary key column. I created a web form in C# in .NET platform which is locally hosted. I have a problem when i try to enter data from the web form, primary key column is not automatically filled when i fill other fields, it does not take any value i enter.

1. when i enter a value by myself it says"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Product' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."
2. When I don't enter a value it says;

   > Incorrect syntax near ','.
   >   Source Error:
   >
   > Line 41:             objCommand.Connection=objConnection;
   >
   > Line 42:             objCommand.CommandText = "Insert into
   >   Product(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,ProductName,ProductDescription,UnitCost,Quantity,TotalAmountToBePaid) values ('" + tbcustomername.Text+ "','" + tbcustomeraddress.Text + "'," + tbinvoicenumber.Text + ",'"+tbinvoicedate.Text + "','" + tbproductname.Text + "','" + tbproductdescription.Text + "'," + tbunitcost.Text + "," + tbquantity.Text + "," + tbamounttobepaid.Text + ")";
   >
   > Line 43:             objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   >
   > Line 44:
   >
   > Line 45:

Because i have autoincremented it, i wish to obtain a value automatically while i m filling other columns but that does not happen. What do i do?

Comment: please review my edits to your question, I've tidied up as best I can, I don't think I removed anything important, but there was a floating `"` below the `Line 45:` line in your code-block.

Comment: Consider using parameterised queries or stored procedures - or at least use 'string.format' e.g. string.Format("INSERT INTO Table VALUES ({0}, '{1}', {2})", 1, "Some Value", 55); It's much more readable

Answer (score 1):

you can change your command.

```
objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Product " +
   "(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,InvoiceNumber,InvoiceDate,ProductName,"+  
   "ProductDescription,UnitCost,Quantity,TotalAmountToBePaid) VALUES " + 
   "(@cname, @caddress, @inumber, @idate, @pname, @pdesc, @unitcost, @qty, @total); " +
   "SELECT SCOPE_IDENITY();";

objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cname", tbcustomername.Text));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@caddress", tbcustomeraddress.Text));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inumber", int.Parse(tbinvoicenumber.Text)));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idate", DateTime.Parse(tbinvoicedate.Text)));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pname", tbproductname.Text));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdesc", tbproductdescription.Text));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unitcost", decimal.Parse(tbunitcost.Text)));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qty", int.Parse(tbquantity.Text)));
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total", decimal.Parse(tbamounttobepaid.Text)));

int id = (int)objCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

This will return the last identity inserted in this transaction wich is the one you want to access.
It is good to remember that you can send multiple statements in a single command.

And as @Wiktor_Zychla says in the comment below it is better coding practice to use parameters in your queries to escape from sql injection.

Comment: As we are here not only to help each other but also to promote better coding, consider editing the response to use a parametrized query.